# How do I divide a cost by a length of time (say 12 months) in order to return a monthly cost

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I am trying to do this calculation: divide a cost by a length of time (say 12 months) in order to return a monthly cost. I am able to return a value from the db but I am doing this totally wrong and I am stuck. I have also tried to use annotate instead of aggregate with no luck.

From views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
 total_cost = Apprentice.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('cost__cost'))['cost__cost__sum']
 monthly_cost = Apprentice.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('p_time__duration'))['p_time__duration__sum']
 return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'total_cost': total_cost, 'monthly_cost': monthly_cost})
```

From template

```
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Total monthly spend</h5>
        <p class="card-text"><strong></strong>£{{ monthly_cost | intcomma }}</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

From models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone



class Division(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

 def __str__(self):
     return self.name


class Department(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
 division = models.ForeignKey(Division, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

 def __str__(self):
     return self.name


class Programme(models.Model):
 p_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

 def __str__(self):
     return self.p_name


class ProgrammeDuration(models.Model):
 program = models.ForeignKey(Programme, unique=True, 
 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 duration = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.duration)


class Cost(models.Model):
p_name = models.ForeignKey(Programme, related_name='cost', 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
cost = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.cost)


class Apprentice(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 role = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 p_name = models.ForeignKey(Programme, related_name='name', 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 p_time = models.ForeignKey(ProgrammeDuration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 dept = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 div = models.ForeignKey(Division, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 cost = models.ForeignKey(Cost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
 on_course = models.BooleanField(null=True)
 left_course = models.BooleanField(null=True)
 start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
 finish_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
 notes = models.TextField(null=True)

 def __str__(self):
     return self.name
```

Input from db

[image]

[image]

Rendered html

[image]

In summary, I am trying to divide the cost by the duration in months to return a monthly cost.

Comment: Can you show us your input data and what the output HTML looks like?

Comment: more importantly your models.py

Comment: Sure, will update post. Thanks

Comment: there are a lot of date fields, by which field do you wanna group your cost?

Comment: This is where I am confused. I want to load all of those months in and then divide them by the programs individual cost in order to come up with a monthly cost e.g £4750/18 and £27000/36 and then render it as one value to the user under "total monthly spend" on the template

Comment: I think your bigger problem is database design. Apprentice have ForeignKey(FK)  for program, cost and program_duration; whilst Program has FK for program_duration and Cost has FK for Program. A ton of relations going around, most of them redundant.

Comment: Noted, thank you - I am learning

Comment: I can help fixing those, if you can briefly explain what are you trying to achieve with these models. I mean what model should do what

Comment: Thank you - so apprentice is obviously the core model where the actual person is stored. The other models are there to store the other data like costs, programmes, departments and so on. I went a bit mad with the FK's because I wanted to ensure that I could relate all of the data to a person e.g I want to know which department a person works in and what programme they are on and it's duration. It sounds rediculous just thinking about it, I know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206317/discussion-between-ian-probets-and-engin-ipek).

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong value inside monthly_cost it`s a total_duration not monthly_cost. To get monthly_cost you need to divide cost__cost__sum on p_time__duration__sum:

```
total_cost = Apprentice.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('cost__cost'))['cost__cost__sum'] 
total_duration = Apprentice.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('p_time__duration'))['p_time__duration__sum'] 
monthly_cost = total_cost/ total_duration
```

Comment: This works in part. However, when I run it like this it will only divide one value rather than all of the returned values from the db. So for instance, if I have 3 programmes that cost 7800/24 (£325/mo) it just displays £325 rather than £975